# Is there a way to rotate individual pixel from a ImageData data array?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

With the following function I create seperate pixels and put them on the canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;



function imageData() {
  var id = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
  var pixels = id.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasWidth);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasHeight);
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var off = (y * id.width + x) * 4;
    pixels[off] = r;
    pixels[off + 1] = g;
    pixels[off + 2] = b;
    pixels[off + 3] = 255;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(id, 0, 0);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body onload="imageData()" >
  
  <canvas id="canvas" width="50" height="50">
  
  
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a way to rotate the individual pixels? I tried rotating the context in general, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'rotate'?

Comment: What do you mean by rotate? I mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate. All the context methods don't work with this data array it seems. I can't f.e. seem to scale the canvas with css either.

Comment: You can treat pixel as point, so you can rotate this point around sth (other point or axis) see [this demo](https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point/)

Comment: If you need help with sth, give us more context what you want to achieve

Comment: Is there a way to rotate individual pixel from a data array? So, the pixels drawn on the canvas need to be rotated.

Comment: @bbpoopaa rotated around what?

Comment: Your question: `Is there a way to rotate individual pixel from a data array?` ... the answer is `Yes`, the demo from @Porok12  breaks down the math how to do it ... in your code you have not tried anything, please at least try something

Comment: Doesn't matter. I can't even seem to rotate the general canvas where the pixels are dawn onto, but this might be a way of achieving what I want. But ideally, I want to rotate the pixel around its own axis, or some other point.

Comment: How would you even put that in the array @HelderSepulveda

Comment: Your answer doesn't even make any sense with the method I'm using..

Comment: Start with simple example. Try to draw circle you will need to calculate x and y coordinates using formula from [linked demo](https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point)

Comment: Ya'll should probably stop whining and instead maybe try and help. No reason for you to come here in the first place.

Comment: @Porok12 the problem is than how can I put that in the data array? I don't see the connection

Comment: You may also be interested in [bresenham algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). If you for e.g. have a line from A to B you must have rasterization algorithm to convert it to your array of pixels.

Comment: bro just get out lol

Comment: @Porok12 I still don't think we're talking about the same thing, or like I said; I'm not seeing the connection. Take the first pixel, it's from `pixels[0]` to `[4]` in the array:  where in the assignment for putting in the (random) rgba integers do I put in a formulate to rotate it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`putImageData()` will really "put" the pixels in place on the canvas buffer, ignoring all of the context's attributes when doing so: global-alpha, composite mode, transformation matrix, etc.

To do what you want, you'll need to create a bitmap version of your `ImageData` object first.
And to do so, the best is to use the [`createImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) method which returns a Promise that will resolve to an `ImageBitmap` object that you will be able to draw on your context using `drawImage()`, which is affected by the context's state.

```js
(async () => {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
const bmp = await createImageBitmap(imageData());
let angle = 0;
anim();

function anim() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.translate(bmp.width/2, bmp.height/2);
  ctx.rotate(angle+=Math.PI/180);
  ctx.drawImage(bmp, -bmp.width/2, -bmp.height/2);
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}

function imageData() {
  var id = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
  var pixels = id.data;

  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasWidth);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasHeight);
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var off = (y * id.width + x) * 4;
    pixels[off] = r;
    pixels[off + 1] = g;
    pixels[off + 2] = b;
    pixels[off + 3] = 255;
  }
 return id;

}
})().catch(console.error);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for, Tysm. I remember reading about ImageBitmap but I don't see the connections, that f.e. you can use it with ImageData. It's definitely clearer now. I'll surely find a way to implement these answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have (dumb) example drawing circle. You need some math knowledge to understand what is going on. This example have to show you how to convert x,y to pixel array.

Basically you must keep in mind that we will do rotation in Cartesian coordinate system and then raster points, lines, circles to pixel array.

If you want "rotate pixel" `pixels[0...3]` you need to "convert" it to Point:

```
var width = 100
var height = 100
var index = 2 // third pixel
var x = index % width
var y = index / width
var r = pixels[(index + 0) * 4]
var g = pixels[(index + 1) * 4]
var b = pixels[(index + 2) * 4]
var point = {
    x, y, r, g, b
}
```

Now with point you can apply some formulas, and then rasterize it again (you will also need to clear previous position manually). Please find some tutorials how to rotate point eg. [this](https://danceswithcode.net/engineeringnotes/rotations_in_2d/rotations_in_2d.html)

You can also read how some libraries, engines works, or read some articles about rasterization etc.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

console.log(width, height)

function imageData() {
  var id = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 250, 250);
  var pixels = id.data;
  
  /*for (var x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    for (var y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
      var off = (x + y * width) * 4;
      pixels[off + 0] = 0;
      pixels[off + 1] = 0;
      pixels[off + 2] = 0;
      pixels[off + 3] = 255;
    }
  }*/
  
  var r = 50;
  var offX = 100;
  var offY = 100;
  var iterations = 1000;
  for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      var angle = 2 * Math.PI * (i / iterations);
      var x = offX + Math.floor(Math.sin(angle) * r);
      var y = offY + Math.floor(Math.cos(angle) * r);
      var off = (x + y * width) * 4;
      pixels[off + 0] = 255;
      pixels[off + 1] = 0;
      pixels[off + 2] = 0;
      pixels[off + 3] = 255;
  }
  
  ctx.putImageData(id, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body onload="imageData()" >
  <canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good explanation and great example ... but from the comments I get a feeling the OP is not going to understand how your circle is a rotation of a pixel

Comment: This is a nice approach. It's not exactly what I meant, but haven't thought about doing it like this either. It'll definitely come of use, if not for what I'm trying to achieve anyway.